# Use DLT table from one pipeline in another pipeline

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

If I have a DLT pipeline that creates a streaming live table called customers, how can I use that table in another pipeline?

So,

- Pipeline A:

```sql
CREATE OR REFRESH STREAMING LIVE TABLE customers AS
```

- Pipeline B:

```sql
CREATE OR REFRESH STREAMING LIVE TABLE sales AS
                  SELECT * FROM source a
                  INNER JOIN STREAM(LIVE.customers)
```

That does not work since it says it does not have access to the customers dataset.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The `LIVE` keyword could be used only for references inside the same pipeline ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/workflows/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-sql-ref#--sql-datasets)).  To refer a table from another pipeline you need to use it's full name as `database.name`.

For production usage it's better to define the name of the table as a configuration parameter (because database names could be different) - then you should be able to refer to it using the `${conf_name}` syntax.

Comment: databasename.tablename  is not helping ,still getting the error 

pyspark.errors.exceptions.AnalysisException: Failed to read dataset 'databsename.tablename' Dataset is not defined in the pipeline.